# Salesforce OAuth access token vs SID

Tags: oauth, salesforce, access-token

I am writing an app for salesforce, and I am using OAuth 2 web server flow to authenticate the app. When I look at the sid inside the salesforce SID cookie it's different from access token I get through OAuth. I verified that with both SID and access token I can access the API. What is the difference between using the SID and access token. Is their access level different? Their expiration is different? I was under the impression that the value of both should be the same. I was surprised when I saw they are different but I can use both to access the API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OAuth session will have the level of access as defined by the `scope` that is was created with. If it has the `web` or `full` scopes then it can be used to access the standard Salesforce UI in the same way the the sid cookie can.

They are however separate/distinct sessions. This allows one to logout without affecting the other. For instance, you probably wouldn't expect you active web session to end if you logout of a third party app/tool that is only interacting with the API.

You can learn a bit about the types of session from the User Session Information page at: Setup > Administration Setup > Security Controls > Session Management.

See also: [Understanding User Session Information](https://help.salesforce.com/htviewhelpdoc?id=security_user_session_info.htm&siteLang=en_US)